# Disable animate when condition is met jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may be an easy question and perhaps I am missing something here.

The desired effect would be when a user clicks on the `.left` or `.right` href tags, the `.tabs` scroller will scroll left or right by `105px` every time.  This part is working.

Where I am running into a road block is how to disable the animate effect when the `.tabs` div's css is at `0px` or at the end of the div.  This seems like it could easily be accomplished with `offset` or `position` but both of these are giving me a different value.  I believe it's because the `.tabs` div is actually centered using `magin: 0 auto`.

Trying to retrieve the `css("left")` and writing a conditional `if == 0` statement is also a bust.

Am I missing something here?  Should I not be trying to disable the `left` button based on position?  Is there an easier way to do this?

```
$(".right").click(function () {
    $(".tabs").animate({
        left: '-=105'
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
$(".left").click(function () {
    $(".tabs").animate({
        left: '+=105'
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Whats the problem here 'Trying to retrieve the css("left") and writing a conditional if == 0 statement is also a bust' ?

Comment: Returns `0px` which is the correct value, but when I run the conditional, it doesn't work?  Is it because it's returning as a string?  Should I try to `parseInt`?

Comment: `parseInt(css('left')) === 0` or simply use `css('left') === '0px'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments in his question,

`$(".tabs").css('left')` returns value in `px`

So, to compare, either you do

`$(".tabs").css('left') === '0px'`

OR

`parseInt($(".tabs").css('left')) === 0`